# Как в argparse сделать позиционные аргументы необязательными по очереди?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Прошу прощения, вопрос наверно не очень умный, но просто я только 2й день штудирую argparse и никак не могу понять как мне сделать так, чтобы позиционные аргументы были необязательными по очереди.

Вот код:

```
import subprocess
import argparse
import re


def create_parser():  # создание парсера
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--timer', action='store_const', const=True)
    parser.add_argument('timer_name')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--service', action='store_const', const=True)
    parser.add_argument('service_name')
    return parser


def check_is_active(timer_name):  # проверка активности таймера
    command = f'sudo systemctl is-active {timer_name}.timer'
    answer = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True).stdout
    if 'inactive' in answer:
        return False
    return True


def find_timer_info(timer_name: str):  # функция вывода состояния таймера
    command = f'sudo systemctl list-timers | grep {timer_name}.timer | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 1- '
    patern = f'(?<=left).*(?={timer_name}\.timer)'
    answer = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True).stdout
    answer_re = re.findall(patern, answer)
    if check_is_active(timer_name):
        print(f'{timer_name} is active, last started {answer_re[0]}')
    else:
        print('Timer is not active')


def find_service_info(service_name):  # функция вывода состояния сервиса
    command_user = f'sudo ps auxf | grep {service_name} | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 1 | head -n1'
    user = subprocess.run(command_user, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True).stdout
    command_status = f'sudo systemctl list-units --type service | grep {service_name} | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 4'
    status = subprocess.run(command_status, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True).stdout.strip()
    command_last_started = f'sudo systemctl  status {service_name} | grep Active:'
    last_started = subprocess.run(command_last_started, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True).stdout
    if 'inactive' in last_started:
        print(f'{status}  {user}')
    else:
        print(f'{user.strip()}  {last_started}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = create_parser()
    namespace = parser.parse_args()
    print(namespace)
    if namespace.timer:
        find_timer_info(namespace.timer_name)
    elif namespace.service:
        find_service_info(namespace.service_name)
```

Объясню что мне надо: мне надо (желательно с минимальными изменениями в коде, потому что я его второй день пишу =) чтобы я мог вызывать скрипт по очереди либо `python3 task2.py --timer <timer_name>` , либо `python3 task2.py --service <service_name>`
Сейчас оба аргумента `timer_name` и `service_name` являются обязательными, и даже если сделать один необязательным, то всё равно важен порядок , т.е. если я например установлю `timer_name` необязательным, то при написании `python3 task2.py --service <service_name>`
всё равно получится, что поскольку он позиционный, то вместо service_name получится timer_name , т.к. он идёт первым.

Хочу отметить, что я хотел бы получить именно такой синтаксис, как я указал выше, т.е. `python3 task2.py --service <service_name>` . Хотелось бы так же обойтись без субпарсеров по возможности, если это возможно.

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если написать вот так, опуская ненужные подробности, которые приведены в вопросе, то это обеспечит вам желаемое поведение:

```
def create_parser():  # создание парсера
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--timer')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--service')
    return parser

# ... ничего не меняем

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ... ничего не меняем
    if namespace.timer:
        find_timer_info(namespace.timer)
    elif namespace.service:
        find_service_info(namespace.service)
```

```
$ python3 task2.py -t 1
Namespace(service=None, timer='1')
find_timer_info('1') CALLED

$ python3 task2.py -s 1
Namespace(service='1', timer=None)
find_service_info('1') CALLED
```

Полезно еще добавить [взаимоисключающую группу](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion), чтобы явно не давать пользователю указать оба аргумента сразу и обязать указывать именно один.

```
def create_parser():  # создание парсера
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('-t', '--timer')
    group.add_argument('-s', '--service')
    return parser
```

```
$ python3 task2.py -s 1 -t 1
usage: task2.py [-h] [-t TIMER | -s SERVICE]
task2.py: error: argument -t/--timer: not allowed with argument -s/--service

$ python3 task2.py -t 1 -s 1
usage: task2.py [-h] [-t TIMER | -s SERVICE]
task2.py: error: argument -s/--service: not allowed with argument -t/--timer

$ python3 task2.py
usage: task2.py [-h] (-t TIMER | -s SERVICE)
task2.py: error: one of the arguments -t/--timer -s/--service is required
```